# Residual Bootstrap for Lasso Inference

Tags: confidence-interval, bootstrap, inference, residuals, lasso

I am a bit confused why the standard residual bootstrap fails to make consistent inference for lasso. Especially, it is claimed that the standard residual bootstrap fails to reproduced the signs of the zero components. Why is this the case? Also why does the modified residual bootstrap (threshold bootstrap) helps to solve the problem here? As to me, the modified residual bootstrap applies a second shrinkage to the small lasso estimates and that is it? I have read the following papers already but still not quite understand:

Knight&Fu(2000)

A. Chatterjee&S. N. Lahiri (2011) Bootstrapping lasso estimators

A. Chatterjee&S. N. Lahiri (2010) Asymptotic properties of the residual bootstrap

Both intuitive explanation and mathematical justification are welcome! Also, 
please explain in a way that an undergraduate would understand.